# Replace values in numpy arrays not working

Tags: python, numpy, replace

I have the following problem, and I'd be glad if somebody could explain to me why this is happening.

So, I have this numpy array:

```
[[ 0.          2.68530063  2.68530063  4.65107712  4.65107712  5.37060126
   2.68530063  4.65107712  4.65107712  5.37060126]
 [ 2.68530063  0.          4.65107712  2.68530063  5.37060126  4.65107712
   4.65107712  2.68530063  5.37060126  4.65107712]
 [ 2.68530063  4.65107712  0.          5.37060126  2.68530063  4.65107713
   4.65107712  7.10463766  7.10463766  8.05590189]
 [ 4.65107712  2.68530063  5.37060126  0.          4.65107713  2.68530063
   7.10463766  4.65107712  8.05590189  7.10463766]
 [ 4.65107712  5.37060126  2.68530063  4.65107713  0.          2.68530063
   7.10463766  8.05590189  9.30215425  9.68198911]
 [ 5.37060126  4.65107712  4.65107713  2.68530063  2.68530063  0.
   8.05590189  7.10463766  9.68198911  9.30215425]
 [ 2.68530063  4.65107712  4.65107712  7.10463766  7.10463766  8.05590189
   0.          5.37060126  2.68530063  4.65107713]
 [ 4.65107712  2.68530063  7.10463766  4.65107712  8.05590189  7.10463766
   5.37060126  0.          4.65107713  2.68530063]
 [ 4.65107712  5.37060126  7.10463766  8.05590189  9.30215425  9.68198911
   2.68530063  4.65107713  0.          2.68530063]
 [ 5.37060126  4.65107712  8.05590189  7.10463766  9.68198911  9.30215425
   4.65107713  2.68530063  2.68530063  0.        ]]
```

And I want to perform replacements as follows: a) values in array == 0, I want them to be 1. b) values in array == 2.68530063, I want them to be -1, and c) values > 2.68530063 I want them to be 0.

I found that a very compact a nice way of doing it would be this one:

```
distances[distances==0.00000000]  = 1
distances[distances > 2.68530063] = 0
distances[distances==2.68530063]  = -1
```

However, my new array output is this:

```
[[ 1.         -1.          2.68530063  0.          0.          0.
   2.68530063  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [-1.          1.          0.          2.68530063  0.          0.          0.
   2.68530063  0.          0.        ]
 [ 2.68530063  0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          2.68530063  0.          1.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          1.         -1.          0.
   0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.         -1.          1.          0.
   0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 2.68530063  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.
   0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          2.68530063  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   1.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          1.         -1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.         -1.          1.        ]]
```

My very big doubt here is: why some values == 2.68530063 remains in my numpy array? I really don't get why given that the condition I imposed should be for all values == 2.68530063 (just as it works correctly for the other conditions).  And second, what would be then a way of replace correctly a numpy array. I'd like to thank you very much in advance, and happy new year 2014.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array elements that display as `2.68530063` may not be exactly equal to `2.68530063`. NumPy truncates array elements for display purposes, and rounding error in the computations that produced your array may have caused elements to have values slightly off from what you'd expect. You can use `numpy.isclose` to perform comparisons within a tolerance:

```
distances[numpy.isclose(distances, 0)]  = 1
distances[distances > 2.68530063] = 0
distances[numpy.isclose(distances, 2.68530063)]  = -1
```

Also, note that the order you perform these assignments in is important. When you compare `distances > 2.68530063`, the `distances` values that used to equal 0 will now be 1. That might cause bugs if you're not careful.

Comment: I will take a look at `numpy.isclose`. Thanks for pointing out the importance on the order in which assignments are performed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
distances[distances == 0]  = 1
distances[distances > 2.685300635] = 0
distances[distances > 2.685300625 and distances < 2.685300635]          = -1
```

?

I have seen this behavior before when trying to use specific values. Basically, 2.68530063 may not be exactly equal to 2.68530063 in memory. It is an approximation to the nearest value represented by the specified number of decimal places ...

Edit:
The last check should be:

```
distances[(distances > 2.685300625) * (distances < 2.685300635)] = -1
```

I think that last one should work ...

Comment: The syntax for the third assignment is wrong. `and` doesn't work for this.

Comment: @user3135460 I think you are right about this assumption of value being different in memory. I tried also this:


`Check = distances==0`      
`Check2 = distances>2.68530063`    
Check3 = distances==2.68530063  
if np.all(Check):  
    distances[Check] = 1 
if np.all(Check2):  
    distances[Check2] = 0
if np.all(Check3):  
    distances[Check3] = -1  
    print distances

Comment: @muammar: Why the `np.all` checks?

Comment: sorry about that. shoud have checked it. You can try something aong the lines of:
    distances[(distances > 2.685300625) * (distances < 2.685300635)]          = -1

Comment: @user2357112 I was trying to check if I could get what I wanted by using the `np.all` (before the distances[arguments]). I did it to confirm that values in memory where indeed not exactly 2.68530063.

Comment: @muammar: That's not what `np.all` does, though. `np.all(Check1)` would only be true if every single element of `distances` was equal to 0.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for clarifying this. I think I didn't RTFM very well :(.